# How do I get last inserted record ID?

Tags: 7, database

I want to get the record ID for the last inserted row in a database table. I am trying to use `db_last_insert_id()`, but it is throwing an exception.

> Call to undefined function `db_last_insert_id()`

How do I get last inserted record ID?

Comment: That function is not available in D7. http://drupal.org/node/729970

Answer (score 15):

In Drupal 6 you would use code similar to the following.

```
db_query("INSERT INTO {mytable} (intvar, stringvar, floatvar) VALUES (%d, '%s', %f)", 5, 'hello world', 3.14);
$id = db_last_insert_id('mytable', 'id_fieldname');
```

The Drupal 7 equivalent code is the following.

```
$id = db_insert('mytable')
  ->fields(array(
    'intvar' => 5,
    'stringvar' => 'hello world',
    'floatvar' => 3.14,
  ))
  ->execute();
```

Comment: I want newly inserted record id from a particular table from the db.Actually I need Newly Registered UserId(uid) in Rules how can i acheive it

Comment: Do not forget to specify table name and field name in `function db_last_insert_id($table, $field)`

Answer (score 11):

If you don't control the particular insert query yourself, you could always use a plain old SQL query:

```
$last_id = db_query('SELECT MAX(id_col) FROM {table}')->fetchField();
```

Comment: I tried using Max(uid) , but i am getting the record above the last record

Comment: Then the record hasn't been inserted yet, so there's no new uid available

Comment: I am able to see the new record in the database but i am not getting the Id of that record

Comment: Nope, that's impossible :) If you can see the uid in the database, logically selecting `MAX(uid)` _must_ return that uid. If not your MySQL server is very very broken

Comment: That would be possible only if your function is called just before the last record is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $id = db_insert('mytable')
       ->fields(array(
       'intvar' => 5,
       'stringvar' => 'hello world',
       'floatvar' => 3.14,
       ))
       ->execute();
```

$id contains the last inserted id of the table.
just do echo $id.

Answer (score 0):

If fore some reason you need to get a fields value before inserting it this is a work around to do it with.

```
function _get_id($tableName, $fieldName) {

    $select = db_select($tableName, 'o');
    $fields = array(
        $fieldName,
    );
    $select->fields('o', $fields);
    $result = $select->orderBy($fieldName)->range(0,1)->execute()->fetchAll();
    return $result[0];
}

$lastId = _get_id('table_name' , 'uid');
```

Answer (score 0):

A crude trick, but it works:

```
$myInsertID = db_query("INSERT INTO {fred} (fld1,fld2) VALUES ('a','b')", array(), array('return' => Database::RETURN_INSERT_ID));
```

or

```
$myInsertID = db_query("INSERT INTO {fred} (fld1,fld2) VALUES ('%s','%s')", array('a','b'), array('return' => Database::RETURN_INSERT_ID));
```